# Mod Rewrite Htaccess for Fake sub Directories and directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create fake directories to redirect specific parameters to specific subdirectories as such:
From: www.example.com/sys/signup
  To: www.example.com/system/ext.php?t=signup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect the browser from the URL with the query string to the one without, then you need to internally rewrite the URL *back* to the one with the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect the browser to clean URL
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+system/ext\.php\?t=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^ /sys/%1? [L,R]

# internally rewrite back to the query string
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^sys/(.*)$ /system/ext.php?t=$1 [L,QSA]
```